# PYTHON PACKAGE ISSUES: Can't import __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

My hierarchy is this:

```
Main_Directory/
    Package/
         __init__.py
         a.py(containing class a)
         b.py(containing class b)
         path.py
     test.py
```

**__init__.py**

```
print(IN init)

from a import a

from b import b

print(DONE)
```

**test.py**

```
print(IN TEST)

from package import a

from package import b
```

**when I'm running __init__.py,**

**I'm getting**

> IN INIT
>
> DONE

**when I'm running test.py,**

**I'm getting**

> IN TEST
>
> IN INIT

module not found 'a'

**what to do?**

Answer (score 0):

Add a dot before each module in `__init__.py`'s import statements. This specifies relative import:

```
from .a import a
from .b import b
```

Alternatively specify an absolute import using the package name:

```
from package.a import a
from package.b import b
```

Comment: In a and b I'm importing one more module named path.py. after applying this case, I cant Import data from path.py in a and b.

Comment: Apply the same logic. Try `import package.path`, or `from package import path`. You could also use relative import: `from . import path`.